# Header file Error for Kernel Compliation Linux

Tags: linux

I am getting the following error when I run the command to install linux headers.

[image: Error Image]

Comment: Post your error as text, not as a screenshot of text. And why are you working with such an ancient kernel?

Comment: I am working on Ubuntu and did recently update the kernel. Is there anything more that I can do?

Comment: You manually typed in version 3.16.0-4, so that's what it's trying to give you, regardless of how updated or not your system is. Why did you do that?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running `sudo apt-get update` or `sudo apt-get upgrade`? This error frequently happens when your list of packages is out of date. The update command will update the list of available packages. The upgrade command will upgrade all of the packages on the system.

Comment: Yes I've tried that but even then, I get this error.